# C# Metro Host WCF Service Library in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, iis, microsoft-metro

I have another annoying Metro/WCF problem :((

I have an app that uses COM object for connecting with some server.
I've created WCF Service Library which connects with server and my Metro application in one solution.
When I run it from Visual Studio debug it goes all ok.

But now I need to deploy my app onto my tablet PC for testing purposes.

I successfully deployed my test-certified Metro-application on the destination PC, but I can't understand, how can I deploy my WCF Service on it and start to listen for connections :(

I heard that I can achieve this by hosting my service in IIS, but I'm extremely new to IIS and I don't understand what-buttons-to-click :((( I don't know what's an ASP and kind of this..

And I want to know - how can my app customers will run my application without needing to deploy IIS and so on.... when my app goes in Windows Store.

Please, if anybody knows how to achieve my goals - help me if you can.

Thank you everybody!!!

Have a nice day :)

Comment: With Metro/Windows Store, I *believe* the intention is that you host the WCF service ***as a service***, i.e. you have some servers somewhere (perhaps in the cloud, perhaps in your own data-centre), and your app connects to *that*. NOT that the end-user gets a WCF server.

Comment: Thanks Marc, but don't you know may I deploy my service in the cloud this time? I just want to run my app without need of Visual Studio on my tablet PC :)

Comment: @Serge it is too general question. If you don't know what WCF is, what IIS is and generally how service consumption works you must first study this topic before asking a question.